# Specifying the number of ticks in between a range

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, data-visualization

I have written code for customizing my x ticks, snippet of the same is below

```
arr_label = ['sum_msg_len','log_count','info_hit','debug_hit','error_hit']
for label in arr_label :

                    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15,6))
                    axes = fig.add_axes([1,1,1,1])
                    axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(plt.LinearLocator(30))
                    axes.tick_params(axis ='x',labelsize=6)

                    axes.plot(df.index,df[label],'g',label =label)
                    axes.legend()


                    fig.autofmt_xdate()
                    fig.savefig('images_indv/'+app_index+"_"+label+".png",bbox_inches='tight')
                    #fig.close()   
                    fig.clf()
```

my requirement is that is have timestamps spaced by minute and i want to plot timestamp vs ('sum_msg_len'/'log_count'/'info_hit'/'debug_hit'/'error_hit') one by one,
but problem is X ticks, i want some specified no of ticks to appear within the range of the data which i am plotting. 
Earlier when i was not specifing any Locator then all the timestamps got overlapped and one cannot read the timestamps properly. So when i try to use a locator, it labels the x-axis with out any relation to the plotted value.
Like if i use LinearLocator(30) it just plots the first 00 to 29 mins in the graph,and if i use LinearLocator(50) it just plots the first 00 to 49 mins in the graph with no change to the y axis values. Plots of both I am putting below. I also tried with different locators Like MultipleLocator and MaxNlocator, but issue sustains

In short, I just want the graph plotted for 21July 00:00:00 to 22 July 00:00:00 which will be 1440 entries but the i want to see around 30-40 intermediate entries mentioned on the plot.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess you would want to use the locators provided by [`matplotlib.dates`](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#dates), e.g. a `MinuteLocator(interval=30)`.

Comment: I used like this
`axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(dts.MinuteLocator(interval=30))`
but now xticks vanished.

Comment: I guess in that case a [mcve] would be needed to find out what's going on.

Comment: Once i put date formatter like below it works
     ` xfmt = dts.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
                    
                    axes.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
                    axes.xaxis.set_major_locator(dts.MinuteLocator(interval=30))`